# Where can I find melodies to practice basic four-part writing?

Tags: theory, satb

I'm a first year Music Student. In our theory classes, we're learning four part writing (SATB).

In every class, our teacher brings a soprano or bass melodic line and asks us to harmonize it. I've tried practicing on my own, but I haven't really found a website or a resource that can provide melodies I can practice harmonization with.

Does anyone know a resource that could help me out? Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Couldn’t you write melodies? They don’t have to be good

Comment: In my understanding there is no melody you can‘t harmonize, though it may be tricky sometimes. So you could pick anything, from children's song to top-10 hit.

Comment: How about some of the choruses in Handel's Messiah or either of the Bach Passions? When you're done you can look to see how your harmonisation differs from the masters'. Otherwise folk tunes.

Comment: This type of music can be found in the public domain, so there will be a lot online. Try looking for Church tune books, hymns, plainsong, etc. You may need to browse a bit to find what you want. This has the tune solo, then harmonized https://books.google.com/books?id=OP1LAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover.

Comment: With a bit of searching you can find unharmonized tunes... https://books.google.com/books?id=AH4yAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA56

Comment: More than anyone could ever exhaust... https://imslp.org/wiki/Die_Melodien_der_deutschen_evangelischen_Kirchenlieder_(Zahn%2C_Johannes)

Answer (score 2):

Get hold of Bach's *371 Harmonized Chorales and 69 Chorale Melodies with figured bass*, published by *Schirmer*, then pick one and harmonize it. If you get stuck you can see what Bach did.

371 should be enough!